# Casperjs "casper.test property is only available using the `casperjs test` command" but not calling casper test

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

The error:

```
casper.test property is only available using the `casperjs test` command
```

Searched my entire codebase for "casper.test", "this.test", "@test", etc, and none are present. Looking at the casper code, one of these needs to be triggered for this error to be raised.

The error is intermittent and only occurs on some casper runs. Has anyone else gotten this bug? I'm running `1.1.0-beta3`.

Answer (score 12):

You can add

```
phantom.casperTest = true;
```

at the top of the test file.

Comment: I don't like this solution even if it works. It sounds like "test" and non-test are separated for a reason. If you aren't using test, you shouldnt do this. Am I wrong? It took me awhile to find out what caused this on mine. You may have to ignore it or make a special handler for it.

Answer (score 4):

Have you launch your script like this ?

`casperjs test yourScript.js`

Comment: No, I just use `casperjs script.js`

Comment: If use `casperjs test yourScript.js`, it will cause an error `Fatal: you can't override the preconfigured casper instance in a test environment.`

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with launching it. Not sure why, but I also received this error on my code before writing to file. It went away after removing...

```
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Again, I dont know what caused the issue. And it may be something else causing it for you. But if you find which piece of code is causing it, I have a solution.

My solution:
Use a handler for errors with a basic variable switch and turn off the error log for that portion of the step.

```
casper.on("error", function(err) {
    if(custLog) {console.log(err);} //log the error
});
```

and in the step...

```
casper.then(function() {
    custLog = false;
    fs.write(fileName, JSON.stringify(content), 'w');
    custLog = true;
});
```

You may or may not need to order the reorder the inner stack there.